# Read text file, modify in certain place and save as a new file in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have 10 text file. Each file contains 1000 rows like this,

```
     1000 atoms
     2 atom types
     -5.0 5.0 xlo xhi
     -5.0 5.0 ylo yhi
     -5.0 5.0 zlo zhi

     Atoms # atomic

     35 1 0.0 -0.2154398 -0.2154398 
     40 1 0.0 -0.2154398 -0.6463404 
     45 1 0.0 -0.2154398 -1.07722
     ..........
```

My aim is to read the file, skip first 9 rows. Then change second column if last column is negative. Then write everything in new file. 
I have tries so far,

```
import itertools
import glob

for i  in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    with open(i) as fin, open('n'+i,'w') as fout:
        fout.write("1000 atoms" "\n"  )
        fout.write("2 atom types" "\n" )
        fout.write("-5.0 5.0 xlo xhi" "\n"  )
        fout.write("-5.0 5.0 ylo yhi" "\n"  )
        fout.write("-5.0 5.0 zlo zhi" "\n" "\n" )
        fout.write("Atoms # atomic" "\n" "\n"  )
        for line in itertools.islice(fin, 9, None): 
            fields = line.split()
            fields[1] = "1" if float(fields[-1]) < 0 else "2"
            fout.write(" ".join(fields) + "\n")
```

This code gives me what I expect. But I wonder how can I write automatically first 9 rows instead of writing them manually using `fout.write("")` in a new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out,

```
import itertools
import glob

for i  in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    with open(i) as fin, open('n'+i,'w') as fout:
        toplines= [next(fin) for x in range(10)]
        fout.write("".join(toplines))
        for line in itertools.islice(fin,None): 
            fields = line.split()
            fields[1] = "1" if float(fields[-1]) < 0 else "2"
            fout.write(" ".join(fields) + "\n")
```

any other innovative answer will be appreciated.